# asp:placeholder contents to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, placeholder

Simple question but I can't find anything on it, is it possible to get the contents of an asp:placeholder to a string? This would be great to do server side if it is possible.

Luke

Comment: What means _"contents of an asp:placeholder to a string"_? Do you want the genrated html or do you want the textual content of a placeholder on serverside?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want the textual content of a placeholder:

```
string textualContent = ((LiteralControl) PlaceHolder1.Controls[0]).Text;
```

Returns 
    `"Hello World"`
 for:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">Hello World</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

If you also want to get the html of the rendered control (and all of it's child-controls):

```
System.IO.TextWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter h = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
PlaceHolder1.RenderControl(h);
string html = tw.ToString();
```

For this aspx (the `GridView` is databound with some sameple data):

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="LblTest" runat="server">Test-Label</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtTest" runat="server" Text="Foo"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1"></asp:GridView>
    <textarea name="TextArea1" rows="2" cols="1">
    First line
    Second line
    </textarea>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

this html will be generated (depends on the browser):

```
<span id="MainContent_LblTest">Test-Label</span><input name="ctl00$MainContent$TxtTest" type="text" value="Foo" id="MainContent_TxtTest" /><div>
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="MainContent_GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th><th scope="col">Text</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>1</td><td>Row #1</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>2</td><td>Row #2</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>3</td><td>Row #3</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>4</td><td>Row #4</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>5</td><td>Row #5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
    <textarea name="TextArea1" rows="2" cols="1">
    First line
    Second line
    </textarea>
```

Note that you need to change your page directive to

```
EnableEventValidation="false"
```

and to override `VerifyRenderingInServerForm` in the `Page`

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
       server control at run time. */
}
```

when calling `RenderControl` manually.

Comment: Do I need to add anything to the override of VerifyRenderingInServerForm for it to work? Currently my repeater control is not working?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't a very helpful description. Nothing gets rendered in the repeater, I have put a breakpoint in the page load of the usercontrol that is called and it does not get hit. Is there a setting in the web.config that is global for EnableEventValidation="false"? All the code in the ascx works and is displayed but the c# codebehind does not get called?

Answer (score 1):

Try the `RenderControl` method of the `Placeholder`.

I did something like this for a `HyperLink`, but as a `Placeholder` inherits from `System.Web.UI.Control`, that should work exactly the same. Something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
using (var stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb))
{
    using (var htmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
        YourPlaceHolder.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
    }
}
return sb.ToString();
```

I've written a short article about this topic: http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/3/asp.net/create-a-control-in-the-codebehind-and-retrieve-its-rendered-output