# How can I get the content of an asp:placeholder into a variable that I can apply an xml transform on?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-placeholder

How can I get the content of an asp:placeholder into a variable that I can apply an xml transform on?

#### Background

I am trying to customise the layout of a .NET web application. It's an enterprise product that allows me to add/remove blocks of content in ascx files, and change css properties. I don't have access to any CodeBehind files (i.e the .cs source code) but I can possibly write my own .cs's if I know how to add those to the .ascx file.
However, the actual content stems from `<asp:placeholders>` so we build up the page by adding/removing calls to place holders.

**The overall aim is to replace the html tables that the place holders generate with e.g. `<div>` so that the application can be responsive.**

#### Example

An example use of a place holder is

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="TreeHead" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

which generates the output

```
<table id="loginBox" style="padding: 2px; margin: 0px;" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
    <td><label for="LM_1">Please enter your username</label></td>
    <td><input name="LM$1$" type="text" id="LM_1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="LM_2">Please enter your password</label></td>
    <td><input name="LM$2$" type="password" id="LM_2"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to convert it to something like this:

```
<div id="loginBox">
<div class="row">
    <div class="element"><label for="LM_1">Please enter your username</label>  </div>
    <div class="element"><input name="LM$1$" type="text" id="LM_1" />  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="element"> <label for="LM_2">Please enter your password</label>       
</div>
    <div class="element"> <input name="LM$2$" type="password" id="LM_2"/>  </div>
</div>
```

#### My idea is

1. Wrap the `<table>` in`<xml></xml>` tags
2. Transform the table using an xslt
3. Extract the resulting `<div id="loginBox"></div>` and output it

I'm thinking that I can achieve this with some inline c# in the .ascx file, like

```
<% string table = "<xml>" + <asp:PlaceHolder ID="TreeHead" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder> + "</xml>"; %>
```

This fails though as I belive any c# code needs to be in the *CodeBehind* file so I’m stuck. If I can get the table into a variable, then I can follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093/how-to-apply-an-xslt-stylesheet-in-c-sharp) to apply the transformation.
I have found a couple of links (see below) that do something similar but I believe those require access to the Codebehind (i.e. *.cs)  files

1. [asp:placeholder contents to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321937/aspplaceholder-contents-to-string)
2. http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/3/asp.net/create-a-control-in-the-codebehind-and-retrieve-its-rendered-output

#### Question

How can I get the content of an asp:placeholder into a variable that I can apply an xml transform on? 
 
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are halfway there... you only need to let placeholder renders, then hide the results, transform it, and render your transformation.

place that on page

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="TreeHead" runat="server" /><%= FinalTable %>
```

and on code behind render and transform your html

```
using (TextWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    using (HtmlTextWriter RenderOnMe = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
        // render the control
        TreeHead.RenderControl(RenderOnMe);

        // transfor here the stringWriter as you like    

        // now add it to the string
        FinalTable = "<xml>" + stringWriter.ToString() + "</xml>";
    }
}

// hide the control, and only render the FinalTable
TreeHead.Visible = false;
```

The `FinalTable` is a page `public string`

Comment: Thats for that. Can the code that generate FinalTable be in a different .cs to that of ID="TreeHead" because I don't have access to the source code of "TreeHead"?

Comment: @kkuilla Must be on the page that hold/render that control. However the RenderControl is not always make what you expect especially on complex controls, you need to make a test.

Comment: At the top of my .ascx file, it says `<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="IndexMain.ascx.cs"`
I don't have access to this file as this is maintained by the software manufacturer. Can I add another CodeBehind and put RenderOnMe there so that the top of the .ascx file looks like
`<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="PublicMain.ascx.cs" 
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="RenderOnMe.ascx.cs"`?

Comment: @kkuilla This is a different and probably complex question. Make a new question about that.