# How to check if ContentPlaceHolder is empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to check if ContentPlaceHolder is absolutely empty?

In the ContentPlaceHolder have text only, without tags and controls.

Example Page.Master:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="Content" />
```

Example Test.aspx:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content">
    Custom text without controls. Content.Controls.Count is 0 and Content.HasControls is false.
</asp:Content>
```

What I need to do is that when the placeholder is empty put a default content is in another control.

Overwrite tried twice for the same placeholder but I get error when dynamic load.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement a method that will render the content control into a string, then check the string to find wheahter it contains any non-white space chars:

```
private bool HasContent(Control ctrl)
{
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    using (var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb)) 
    {
        using(var tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            ctrl.RenderControl(tw);
        }
    }

    var output = sb.ToString().Trim();

    return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(output);
}

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var placeholder = Master.FindControl("FeaturedContent");
    var hasContent = HasContent(placeholder);
}
```

Comment: Controls.Count is 0 but have text, is not empty.

Comment: Sorry, a templated server control does not convert markup from the .aspx page into a server control. I've updated my answer with one possible approach you can use: render the content control in a string builder and check if there are any non-white space characters in it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the `ContentPLaceHolder` on the master page first. Then you can cast the first control(which always exists) to `LiteralControl` and use it's `Text` property.

So this works as expected from `Page_Load` of the content-page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cph = Page.Master.FindControl("Content") as ContentPlaceHolder;
    if (contentPlaceHolder != null)
    {
        string textualContent = ((LiteralControl) cph.Controls[0]).Text;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textualContent))
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio says: ArgumentOutOfRangeException. My code is: string textualContent = ((LiteralControl) CustomHeader.Controls[0]).Text;
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textualContent))
   {
    /* Carga la cabecera por defecto */
    UserControl head = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/layout/Themes/" + config.themeSelected + "/header.ascx");
    CustomHeader.Controls.Add(head);
   }

Comment: Same problem, break in string textualContent = ((LiteralControl)cph.Controls[0]).Text; with same error. When overide contents says: La colección de controles no puede modificarse porque el control contiene bloques de código (por ej. <% ... %>).

Comment: @WHK: I have tested it with your aspx and master code. It shows `Custom text without controls. Content.Controls.Count is 0 and Content.HasControls is false.` as `textualContent`.

Comment: Yes, i use visual studio 2012, asp in c# and not use mvc.

Comment: @WHK: I'm using Visual Studio 2010, however, that doesnt matter. So im not sure why it works for me and not for you. If a control like `PlaceHolder` or `ContentPlaceHolder` contains no controls but text ASP.NET injets automatically an "invisible" control of type `LiteralControl` to it which `Text` property contains the text. Here is my answer on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14322105/284240

Comment: Btw, why have you used the ID `CustomHeader` and showed `Content` in your code above? Also, you haven't used my code to get the reference of the `ContentPlaceHolder` of the master-page(`Page.Master.FindControl...`). Have you used the debugger to check what happens?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have changed, because I am seeing in 4.5 that **`HasControls` DOES return true when there is only literal text in the `Content`**, even a single whitespace.    I do something like this in my master page:

```
<asp:Panel id="SidebarPanel" CssClass="Sidebar" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="SidebarContent" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>

Sub Page_Load(...)
    SidebarPanel.Visible = SidebarContent.HasControls
End Sub
```

This renders the sidebar content, if there is any, inside a `<div class="Sidebar">` -- and avoids creating an empty div on the page when there's no content.

Answer (score 1):

I really didn't want to run all the code for a render or risk that maybe some controls might have states that change after being rendered. So I came up with another approach.

```
public static int ChildrenCount(ContentPlaceHolder placeholder)
{
    int total = 0;
    total += placeholder.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(x => 
        (!(x is ContentPlaceHolder) && !(x is LiteralControl)) ||
        (x is LiteralControl && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((LiteralControl)x).Text))
    ).Count();
    foreach (var child in placeholder.Controls.OfType<ContentPlaceHolder>())
        total += ChildrenCount(child);
    return total;
}
```

For me the text I'd place directly into a Content element would be returned by OfType as a LiteralControl with the appropriate contents. Not only this but my formatting ("\r\n\t") would also be returned the same way. I'd also get ContentPlaceholders for subsequent master pages as they passed the slot in my web pages to the next master page or actual page.

So the task now is to get a count of controls that excludes these ContentPlaceholders and also excludes LiteralControls which are whitespace. This is pretty easy using the **is** operator. We'll just make sure a given control is neither of those types and then count it, or if it is a Literal we check if the contents are all whitespace or not. The last step is to recursively add the results of the same operation for all child ContentPlaceholders so nested master pages work as expected.

And then finally:

```
if (ChildrenCount(MyContentPlaceholder) == 0)
    MyContentPlaceholder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("My default content!"));
```

Answer (score -1):

My 2 cents:

If it's a constant content you'll have to insert AND there will be no `<Content>` at all:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   <!-- Anything here will be inserted if there's no Content -->
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Why the downvote? I think the question was broad enough to include a case like this.

Comment: Because it is not the purpose of the question, there is clearly no content controls but if so whether detectable.