# Why is ContentPlaceHolder.Controls.Count 0 if there are server tags without runat=server?

Tags: asp.net, contentplaceholder, runatserver

In the MasterPage.OnLoad event for Page1 and Page3 I get TitleContent.Controls.Count>0, but for Page2 (as soon as I have server tags without runat=server) the control count is zero. Why is that and how do I check for content in Page2 (lets assume I have no control over Page2 so adding runat=server does not help).

I thought to move it later in the pipeline but control count is still zero at the pre-render stage of the MasterPage and the ContentPlaceHolder control.

(VS2010 ASP.NET Web Forms .Net 4.0)

**MasterPage.aspx:**

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server"/>
```

**Page1.aspx:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent">
    <h1>Heading Text</h1>
</asp:Content>
```

**Page2.aspx:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent">
    <h1><%= HeadingTextFromCode %></h1>
</asp:Content>
```

**Page3.aspx:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent">
    <h1 runat="server"><%= HeadingTextFromCode %></h1>
</asp:Content>
```

Aside:
*What I really wanted to ask was "How do I tell if ContentPlaceHolder is empty" and the only way that works reliably is to render the contents to a string and check if empty as suggested by defrost here:*

[How to check if ContentPlaceHolder is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345469/how-to-check-if-contentplaceholder-is-empty)

That solution works for all three of my scenarios but it seems awkward and repetitive to render to string just to see if it is empty.

Comment: Please post the code you're using to check the counts.

Comment: The code is simply "TitleContent.Controls.Count" in the Page_Load event of the MasterPage. For Page2 this is zero, for Page1 & 3 it is 1.

Comment: to be specific I'm trying something like: TitlePanel.Visible = (TitleContent.Controls.Count > 0);