# How to get and set Placeholder's html content?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, placeholder

my question is about to PlaceHolders. i have been developing asp.net application.(old application. i never prefer this kinda codes style.)

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phTemplates" runat="server" EnableTheming="true">
    <ul id="mytemplateTags">
       <li>K1</li>
       <li>K2</li>
    </ul>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

How can i get K1,K2 by using C# codes. i tried below codes but it doesn't work :

```
public List<UserTemplate> Templates
{
    get
    {
        var templates = phTemplates.Controls.AsQueryable();
        return null;
    }
    set {}
}
```

Comment: Here is a question about getting content of placeholder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321937/aspplaceholder-contents-to-string

Comment: I've never personally used it, but from what I understand I think the [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) might help