# Generated asp:PlaceHolder content to string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question ..
I've been searching for a solution that match with my case but nothing work ..

I have simple Datatable with some data, then I Convert it to HTML and put in to Place Holder in runtime ..
The table has contentEnable=true ..
So, user can edit some data in the table ..

Now, what I want to do is get the updated table back into data table ..

I was follow this link [asp:placeholder contents to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321937/aspplaceholder-contents-to-string)

but still it doesn't work for me ..
can anyone please tell me what's wrong in my code, and tell me how to solve it ..

Here is my Default.aspx code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Panel runat="server">
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <dx:ASPxPageControl ID="ASPxPageControl1" runat="server">
                    <TabPages>
                        <dx:TabPage>
                            <ContentCollection>
                                <dx:ContentControl>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Buat Data" />
                                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PH1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="btn1_Click" Text="Buat Data" />
                                </dx:ContentControl>
                            </ContentCollection>
                        </dx:TabPage>
                    </TabPages>
                </dx:ASPxPageControl>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
</form>
```

And here is my Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("C1", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("C2", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("C3", typeof(string));

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = "Test 1";
        dr[1] = "Test 2";
        dr[2] = "Test 3";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        string html = ConvertDataTableToHTML(dt);

        PH1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html });


    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
    }
    public static string ConvertDataTableToHTML(DataTable dt)
    {
        string html = "<table border='1' class='rerere'>";
        //add header row
        html += "<tr>";
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            html += "<td>" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "</td>";
        html += "</tr>";
        //add rows
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            html += "<tr>";
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                html += "<td contentEditable='true'>" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "</td>";
            html += "</tr>";
        }
        html += "</table>";
        return html.ToString();
    }

    public static DataTable ConvertHTMLTablesToDataTable(string HTML)
    {


        DataTable dt = null;
        DataRow dr = null;
        DataColumn dc = null;
        string TableExpression = "<table[^>]*>(.*?)</table>";
        string HeaderExpression = "<th[^>]*>(.*?)</th>";
        string RowExpression = "<tr[^>]*>(.*?)</tr>";
        string ColumnExpression = "<td[^>]*>(.*?)</td>";
        bool HeadersExist = false;
        int iCurrentColumn = 0;
        int iCurrentRow = 0;

        // Get a match for all the tables in the HTML    
        MatchCollection Tables = Regex.Matches(HTML, TableExpression, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Loop through each table element    
        foreach (Match Table in Tables)
        {

            // Reset the current row counter and the header flag    
            iCurrentRow = 0;
            HeadersExist = false;

            // Add a new table to the DataSet    
            dt = new DataTable();

            // Create the relevant amount of columns for this table (use the headers if they exist, otherwise use default names)    
            if (Table.Value.Contains("<th"))
            {
                // Set the HeadersExist flag    
                HeadersExist = true;

                // Get a match for all the rows in the table    
                MatchCollection Headers = Regex.Matches(Table.Value, HeaderExpression, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                // Loop through each header element    
                foreach (Match Header in Headers)
                {
                    //dt.Columns.Add(Header.Groups(1).ToString);  
                    dt.Columns.Add(Header.Groups[1].ToString());

                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int iColumns = 1; iColumns <= Regex.Matches(Regex.Matches(Regex.Matches(Table.Value, TableExpression, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[0].ToString(), RowExpression, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[0].ToString(), ColumnExpression, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count; iColumns++)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add("Column " + iColumns);
                }
            }

            // Get a match for all the rows in the table    
            MatchCollection Rows = Regex.Matches(Table.Value, RowExpression, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            // Loop through each row element    
            foreach (Match Row in Rows)
            {

                // Only loop through the row if it isn't a header row    
                if (!(iCurrentRow == 0 & HeadersExist == true))
                {

                    // Create a new row and reset the current column counter    
                    dr = dt.NewRow();
                    iCurrentColumn = 0;

                    // Get a match for all the columns in the row    
                    MatchCollection Columns = Regex.Matches(Row.Value, ColumnExpression, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    // Loop through each column element    
                    foreach (Match Column in Columns)
                    {

                        DataColumnCollection columns = dt.Columns;

                        if (!columns.Contains("Column " + iCurrentColumn))
                        {
                            //Add Columns  
                            dt.Columns.Add("Column " + iCurrentColumn);
                        }
                        // Add the value to the DataRow    
                        dr[iCurrentColumn] = Column.Groups[1].ToString();
                        // Increase the current column    
                        iCurrentColumn += 1;

                    }

                    // Add the DataRow to the DataTable    
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                }

                // Increase the current row counter    
                iCurrentRow += 1;
            }


        }

        return (dt);

    }  

    protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.TextWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter h = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
        PH1.RenderControl(h);
        string html = tw.ToString();

        DataTable dt = ConvertHTMLTablesToDataTable(html);
        int n = dt.Rows.Count;

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            string a = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            string b = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            string c = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
        }
    }
```

So, with above code I always getting empty in TextWriter ..
Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Thanks, sorry for my bad English ...

Comment: Why not bind the data to a GridView (which is a table in html) instead of creating your own overly complex converter?

Comment: thanks for your comment, but i have problem to use inline editing in gridview .. can you show me some examples about gridview inline editing?

Comment: The only thing you need to do is add `contentEditable='true'` is the `RowDataBound` event.

Comment: okay, i'll try it .. thanks for reply ..

Answer (score 0):

when you click on button1 , a post back occurs, and page reloads, so you loose content of placeholder

just for testing , try with inserting :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
    }
```

and you will see in debugger that btn1_Click works:

```
string a = "Test 1"
string b = "Test 2"
string c = "Test 3"
```

in your method :

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.TextWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter h = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
        PH1.RenderControl(h);
        string html = tw.ToString();

        DataTable dt = ConvertHTMLTablesToDataTable(html);
        int n = dt.Rows.Count;

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            string a = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            string b = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            string c = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer .. you're right, i have tried it before ... so with my code structure, is it possible to get the table content?

Comment: @MohamadFirdaus you need to make your data persistent, or call loaddata at postback